C program fails executing upon removing unused malloc for char** Array on Windows only
In my C program, I am trying to convert .asm code to pseudo-machine code.
Assembly file used:
ORG 0x10
start   WB 0x05 ; write 0x05 to MBR
        WM 0x400 ; write data on MBR to memory at address 0x400
        WB 0x03 ; write 0x03 to MBR
        WM 0x401 ; write data on MBR to memory at address 0x401
        RM 0x400 ; read address 0x400, store data to MBR
        WACC ; write MBR to ACC (via BUS)
        RM 0x401 ; read data at memory address 0x401, store to MBR
        ADD ; add ACC to MBR (through BUS)
        RACC ; read ACC, store to MBR
        WM 0x402 ; write data on MBR to memory address 0x402
        WB 0x00 ; write 0x00 to MBR
        RM 0x402 ; read address 0x402, store data to MBR
        WACC ; write MBR to ACC (via BUS)
        WB 0x05 ; write 0x05 to MBR
        BRGT here ; compare ACC with MBR, jump to here if greater than
        RACC ; read ACC, store to MBR
        WM 0x403 ; write data on MBR to memory address 0x403
here    SHL ; shift left ACC
        RACC ; read ACC, store to MBR
        WM 0x405 ; write data on MBR to memory at address 0x405
        EOP

Desired output:
ADDR=0x10;BUS=0x30;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x11;BUS=0x05;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x12;BUS=0x0C;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x13;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x14;BUS=0x30;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x15;BUS=0x03;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x16;BUS=0x0C;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x17;BUS=0x01;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x18;BUS=0x14;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x19;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x1A;BUS=0x48;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x1B;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x1C;BUS=0x14;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x1D;BUS=0x01;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x1E;BUS=0xF0;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x1F;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x20;BUS=0x58;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x21;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x22;BUS=0x0C;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x23;BUS=0x02;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x24;BUS=0x30;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x25;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x26;BUS=0x14;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x27;BUS=0x02;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x28;BUS=0x48;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x29;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x2A;BUS=0x30;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x2B;BUS=0x05;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x2C;BUS=0x90;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x2D;BUS=0x32;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x2E;BUS=0x58;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x2F;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x30;BUS=0x0C;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x31;BUS=0x03;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x32;BUS=0xB0;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x33;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x34;BUS=0x58;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x35;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x36;BUS=0x0C;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x37;BUS=0x05;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x38;BUS=0xF8;MainMemory();
ADDR=0x39;BUS=0x00;MainMemory();

I'm encountering a strange issue where the program crashes if I remove a malloc statement for a char** array located in convertAsmToC(), which is weird because the array, branchKeys, is not used anywhere in the code. Apart from that, it compiles and runs successfully on Mac but not on my Windows machine. The malloc statement in question is:
char **branchKeys = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char *));

Already tried debugging the code on lldb with my Mac and it shows no segmentation faults. Even if the malloc statement was removed, it would still run on my Mac. The program compiles for both operating systems. The only difference is that the Mac actually manages to finish executing convertAsmToC() and outputs the text file, while on Windows it just ends without any output and no text file is generated.
For more context, these are my versions of C:

Windows: gcc version 13.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
Mac: Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)

Following are my code files:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "assembler.h"
#define FILE_PATH "./data/assembly.asm"
#define OUTPUT_PATH "./output/assembled.txt"

int getLinesFromFile(FILE *currentFile, char **lines);

int main()
{
    int numLines = 0;
    int conversionStatus;
    char *lines[1024];
    FILE *currentFile = fopen(FILE_PATH, "r");
    numLines = getLinesFromFile(currentFile, lines);
    if (numLines > 0)
    {
        char **assembledLines = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char *));
        if (assembledLines == NULL)
        {
            // If malloc fails, handle the memory allocation failure
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation for assembledLines failed.\n");
            return 1; // Return an error code or handle it as needed
        }
        conversionStatus = assembleToC(assembledLines, lines, numLines);
        if (conversionStatus)
        {
            FILE *file = fopen(OUTPUT_PATH, "w");
            if (file == NULL)
            {
                perror("Failed to open file");
                return 1;
            }

            // Write each string to the file

            for (int i = 0; i < conversionStatus; i++)
            {
                fprintf(file, "%s\n", assembledLines[i]); // Adds a newline after each string
            }

            // Close the file
            fclose(file);
            printf("[SUCCESS] Done assembling %s!\n", FILE_PATH);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("[ERROR] Error assembling %s.\n", FILE_PATH);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[ERROR] Unable to open file %s or file is empty.\n", FILE_PATH);
    }
}

int getLinesFromFile(FILE *currentFile, char **lines)
{
    if (currentFile != NULL)
    {
        int numLines = 0;
        char line[1024];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), currentFile) != NULL)
        {
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0'; // Replace \n in files with \0 null terminator.
            lines[numLines++] = strdup(line); // Copy string to lines array
        }
        fclose(currentFile);
        return numLines;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

assembler.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "assembler.h"

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char opcode;
    int needs_adding;
} INSTRUCTION;

const char *INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_KEYS[] = {
    "ADD", "SUB", "MUL", "AND", "OR", "NOT", "XOR", "SHL", "SHR",
    "WM", "RM", "RIO", "WIO", "WB", "WIB", "WACC", "RACC",
    "SWAP", "BR", "BRE", "BRNE", "BRGT", "BRLT", "EOP"};

const int NUM_INSTRUCTIONS = sizeof(INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_KEYS) / sizeof(INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_KEYS[0]);

const INSTRUCTION INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_VALUES[] = {
    {0xF0, 0}, {0xE8, 0}, {0xD8, 0}, {0xD0, 0}, {0xC8, 0}, {0xC0, 0}, {0xB8, 0}, {0xB0, 0}, {0xA8, 0}, {0x08, 1}, {0x10, 1}, {0x20, 1}, {0x28, 1}, {0x30, 0}, {0x38, 0}, {0x48, 0}, {0x58, 0}, {0x70, 0}, {0x18, 1}, {0xA0, 1}, {0x98, 1}, {0x90, 1}, {0x88, 1}, {0xF8, 0}};

int assembleToC(char **assembledLines, char **extractedLines, int numLines)
{
    int eopExists = checkIfEOPExists(extractedLines, numLines);
    unsigned int startingAddress = getStartingAddress(extractedLines, numLines);
    if (eopExists && startingAddress < 0xFFFF)
    {
        char **branchKeys = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char *)); // Unused but breaks program on Windows if removed.
        int numAssembledLines = convertAsmToC(assembledLines, extractedLines, numLines, startingAddress);
        return numAssembledLines;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR!");
        return 0;
    }
}

int checkIfEOPExists(char **extractedLines, int numLines)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        char *eopExists = strstr(extractedLines[i], "EOP");
        if (eopExists)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned int getStartingAddress(char **extractedLines, int numLines)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int startingAddress = 0x00;
    char extraChar; // Variable to check for extra characters after the hex number

    for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        char *orgExists = strstr(extractedLines[i], "ORG");
        if (orgExists)
        {
            int parsed = sscanf(extractedLines[i], "ORG %x%c", &startingAddress, &extraChar);
            if (parsed == 1)
            {
                return startingAddress;
            }
            else if (parsed == 2)
            {
                printf("[ERROR] Invalid memory address due to unexpected characters.\n");
                return 0xFFFF;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("[ERROR] Invalid memory address format.\n");
                return 0xFFFF;
            }
        }
    }
    return startingAddress;
}

int convertAsmToC(char **assembledLines, char **extractedLines, int numLines, unsigned int startingAddress)
{
    int i, j, numAssembledLines = 0;

    unsigned int *currentAddress = &startingAddress;
    int validAddress = 1;
    char *token;
    char tempLine[256];
    for (i = 1; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        unsigned int instruction, operand;
        strcpy(tempLine, extractedLines[i]);
        token = strtok(tempLine, " \t");

        if (!validAddress)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        while (token != NULL)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < NUM_INSTRUCTIONS; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(token, INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_KEYS[j]) == 0)
                {
                    instruction = INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_VALUES[j].opcode;
                    char *stringOperand = strtok(NULL, " \t");
                    if (stringOperand != NULL)
                    {
                        int parsed = sscanf(stringOperand, "%x", &operand);
                        validAddress = checkValidAddress(token, operand);
                        if (validAddress)
                        {
                            if (INSTRUCTION_TO_HEX_VALUES[j].needs_adding && parsed == 1)
                            {
                                unsigned int current_instruction = (instruction << 8) + operand;
                                instruction = (current_instruction >> 8) & 0xFF;
                                operand = current_instruction & 0xFF;
                            }
                            else if (parsed != 1)
                            {
                                operand = findBranch(stringOperand, extractedLines, currentAddress, numLines, i);
                            }
                            token = NULL;
                            assembledLines[numAssembledLines++] = getInstructionString(instruction, currentAddress);
                            assembledLines[numAssembledLines++] = getInstructionString(operand, currentAddress);
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            free(assembledLines);
                            assembledLines = NULL;
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        operand = 0x00;
                        token = NULL;
                        assembledLines[numAssembledLines++] = getInstructionString(instruction, currentAddress);
                        assembledLines[numAssembledLines++] = getInstructionString(operand, currentAddress);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (token != NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
            }
        }
    }
    return numAssembledLines;
}

int checkValidAddress(char *instruction, unsigned int operand)
{
    if (strcmp(instruction, "WIO") == 0 || strcmp(instruction, "RIO") == 0)
    {
        return operand <= 0x01F;
    }
    else if (strcmp(instruction, "WM") == 0 || strcmp(instruction, "RM") == 0)
    {
        return operand >= 0x400 && operand <= 0x7FF;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

unsigned int findBranch(char *stringOperand, char **extractedLines, unsigned int *currentAddress, int numLines, int currentLine)
{
    unsigned int operand = 0x00;
    if (stringOperand)
    {
        if (strcmp(stringOperand, ";") != 0)
        {
            for (int k = currentLine + 1; k < numLines; k++)
            {
                char *branchFound = strstr(extractedLines[k], stringOperand);
                if (branchFound)
                {
                    operand = (*currentAddress) + (2 * (k - currentLine));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return operand;
}

char *getInstructionString(unsigned int instruction, unsigned int *currentAddress)
{
    char buffer[50];
    int max_len = sizeof(buffer);

    int len = snprintf(buffer, max_len, "ADDR=0x%02X;BUS=0x%02X;MainMemory();", *currentAddress, instruction);
    (*currentAddress)++;
    if (len >= 0 && len < max_len)
    {
        char *result = malloc(len + 1);
        if (result)
        {
            strcpy(result, buffer);
            return result;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *getOperandString(unsigned int operand, unsigned int *currentAddress)
{
    char buffer[50];
    int max_len = sizeof(buffer);

    int len = snprintf(buffer, max_len, "ADDR=0x%02X;BUS=0x%02X;MainMemory();", *currentAddress, operand);
    (*currentAddress)++;
    if (len >= 0 && len < max_len)
    {
        char *result = malloc(len + 1);
        if (result)
        {
            strcpy(result, buffer);
            return result;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

assembler.h
#ifndef ASSEMBLER_H_   
#define ASSEMBLER_H_

int assembleToC(char **assembledLines, char **extractedLines, int numLines);
int convertAsmToC(char **assembledLines, char **extractedLines, int numLines, unsigned int startingAddress);
int checkIfEOPExists(char **extractedLines, int numLines);
unsigned int getStartingAddress(char **extractedLines, int numLines);
int checkValidAddress(char *instruction, unsigned int operand);
unsigned int findBranch(char *stringOperand, char **extractedLines, unsigned int *currentAddress, int numLines, int currentLine);
char *getInstructionString(unsigned int instruction, unsigned int *currentAddress);
char *getOperandString(unsigned int operand, unsigned int *currentAddress);

#endif 


I blindly transformed your two malloc(len + 1); into malloc(len + 1 + 2000); and no more issues. This strongly suggests that you have a buffer overflow here.

Suggest you start with an input file that has 1 instruction in it (perhaps your "memory address" thingy.) Run the program and observe the results. Then, try again with 2 lines of "assembler". Does it work (still?)... Divide and conquer...

In my experience, this behavior -- OK when memory is allocated but not used -- is typically due to nearby code clobbering nearby code/data space.  The buffer you allocate means your code can now clobber "safe" space ( safe because your program allocated it ).  This works even better with statically-declared buffers, but this latter point is moot.  There were times I allocated much more than needed to safe-up my code ( shameful ).

Thanks for the help everyone! It turns out I wasn't allocating enough memory to assembledLines. Initially set to, char **assembledLines = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char *)), this was faulty since it was assuming numLines == numAssembledLines. In this case, it would output TWO assembled lines since there was instruction and operand strings for each line of assembly. All I did was change char **assembledLines = malloc(2 * numLines * sizeof(char *)) to accommodate it and it no longer crashed.

There are many memory related problems (leaks and corruption) with your code. I suggest you to fix those at first.
You are writing to heap memory by mistake (due to the memory problems i mentioned previously) and with the allocation there, your code runs with no problems by luck. Once you remove the allocation from your code, now you are not allowed to write such amount of data to that heap block and overwriting the heap metadata. I'll put the complaints by valgrind (both with and without the allocation) in your code so you can fix them.
with the allocation (working version):
==78194== Invalid write of size 8
==78194==    at 0x109B58: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:128)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194==  Address 0x4a9ed50 is 0 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109425: main (main.c:20)
==78194== 
==78194== Invalid write of size 8
==78194==    at 0x109B96: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:129)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194==  Address 0x4a9ed58 is 8 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109425: main (main.c:20)
==78194== 
==78194== Invalid read of size 8
==78194==    at 0x1094FF: main (main.c:41)
==78194==  Address 0x4a9ed50 is 0 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109425: main (main.c:20)
==78194== 
[SUCCESS] Done assembling test.asm!
==78194== 
==78194== HEAP SUMMARY:
==78194==     in use at exit: 2,739 bytes in 66 blocks
==78194==   total heap usage: 71 allocs, 5 frees, 12,899 bytes allocated
==78194== 
==78194== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109EB4: getInstructionString (assembler.c:204)
==78194==    by 0x109C11: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:143)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109EB4: getInstructionString (assembler.c:204)
==78194==    by 0x109C4F: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:144)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 132 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109EB4: getInstructionString (assembler.c:204)
==78194==    by 0x109B57: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:128)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 132 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109EB4: getInstructionString (assembler.c:204)
==78194==    by 0x109B95: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:129)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 528 bytes in 16 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 5 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109EB4: getInstructionString (assembler.c:204)
==78194==    by 0x109B57: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:128)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 528 bytes in 16 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 6 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109EB4: getInstructionString (assembler.c:204)
==78194==    by 0x109B95: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:129)
==78194==    by 0x109729: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 572 (176 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x10970F: assembleToC (assembler.c:28)
==78194==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78194== 
==78194== 902 (176 direct, 726 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x109425: main (main.c:20)
==78194== 
==78194== 1,001 bytes in 22 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 9
==78194==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78194==    by 0x491958E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==78194==    by 0x109657: getLinesFromFile (main.c:68)
==78194==    by 0x1093FE: main (main.c:17)
==78194== 
==78194== LEAK SUMMARY:
==78194==    definitely lost: 1,617 bytes in 32 blocks
==78194==    indirectly lost: 1,122 bytes in 34 blocks
==78194==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==78194==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==78194==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==78194== 
==78194== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==78194== ERROR SUMMARY: 21 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

without the allocation (crashing version):
==78991== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==78991== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==78991== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==78991== Command: ./osman
==78991== 
==78991== Invalid write of size 8
==78991==    at 0x109B43: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:128)
==78991==    by 0x109714: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78991==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78991==  Address 0x4a9ed50 is 0 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
==78991==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78991==    by 0x109425: main (main.c:20)
==78991== 
==78991== Invalid write of size 8
==78991==    at 0x109B81: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:129)
==78991==    by 0x109714: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78991==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
==78991==  Address 0x4a9ed58 is 8 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
==78991==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==78991==    by 0x109425: main (main.c:20)
==78991== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:303 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 240, hi = 78248064.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==78991==    at 0x5804284A: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x58042977: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x58042B1B: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x5804C8CF: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x5803AE9A: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x580395B7: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x5803DF3D: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x58038868: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x1008E2F1FD: ???
==78991==    by 0x1008CA9F2F: ???
==78991==    by 0x581FCD83: ??? (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==78991==    by 0x1008CA9F17: ???
==78991==    by 0x1008CA9F2F: ???

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 78991)
==78991==    at 0x109BFD: convertAsmToC (assembler.c:143)
==78991==    by 0x109714: assembleToC (assembler.c:29)
==78991==    by 0x109482: main (main.c:27)
client stack range: [0x1FFEFFC000 0x1FFF000FFF] client SP: 0x1FFEFFD7F0
valgrind stack range: [0x1008BAA000 0x1008CA9FFF] top usage: 18744 of 1048576


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.


Thanks for this! Using your valgrind output, I managed to see that I was allocating char **assembledLines = malloc(numLines * sizeof(char *)). This would be fine if each line of assembly would output to one line of assembled lines. In this case, it would output TWO since there was instruction and operand strings. All I did was change char **assembledLines = malloc(2 * numLines * sizeof(char *)) to accommodate it and it no longer crashed. Thanks again!
